# Is it possible to get a value from a dictionay inside another with exact address inside an string?

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {
  "message": "...",
  "type": {
    "color": "...",
    "serverity": "high"
  }
}
```

I have a function that I wanted to return a value by it's address. 
for example:

```
my_func('type\severity')
```

should return: high.
Is there a way to this?

Comment: What you have try so far, can you share more about your implementation?

Comment: serverity? or severity?

Comment: @Emre I just want to know if there is a way to access this way or not. what kind of implementation do you need to see?

Comment: You need to split the address string into its components and then use them as keys in the nested dictionary (hint: use the `split` string method).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre please forget about spelling dude! help me :)

Comment: No, there's no built in way to do what you're looking for. If you've tried to implement it yourself, show what you've tried and describe how it failed.